# Multiple Select Doesn't Work

Tags: php, multiple-select

**EDIT: I edited my question to make it clearer I wish.**

I built a page with a form with several search boxes to search and display values from a database table in a table by the method of $_GET. It works quite good for now.

**WHAT I NEED:** I want some of the search boxes to allow multiple selection but I get the results of only one selection.

**This is the query:**

```
$query_Recordset2 = sprintf("SELECT * FROM satislar WHERE satis_satici LIKE %s AND urun_satilanurun LIKE
%s AND urun_pstnadslhizturu LIKE %s AND akt_aktalan LIKE %s AND satis_modem LIKE %s AND akt_aktdurum LIKE
%s AND akt_ttonayi LIKE %s AND satis_tarih between %s and %s ORDER BY satis_tarih DESC",
```

**This is the select option:**

```
<select name="satici[]" size="4" multiple="multiple" id="satici" size="4" class="span2 nostyle chzn-select" style="margin-top:9px;width:150px;">
                                                <option value="%">TÜM SATICILAR</option>

                                              <?php
do {  
?>
                                              <option value="<?php echo $row_saticilistesi['satis_satici']?>"><?php echo $row_saticilistesi['satis_satici']?></option>
                                              <?php
} while ($row_saticilistesi = mysql_fetch_assoc($saticilistesi));
$rows = mysql_num_rows($saticilistesi);
if($rows > 0) {
  mysql_data_seek($saticilistesi, 0);
  $row_saticilistesi = mysql_fetch_assoc($saticilistesi);
}
?>
```

I'm waiting for your precious ideas.

Comment: Can you maybe post the HTML of this?

Comment: have you ever heard of `$_GET` or `$_POST`?

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5326510/code.html

Comment: Arrgh. I even can't use SO.

Comment: I accidentally keep on kicking enter button.

Answer (score 0):

To use Multiple selects you need to set your HTML like this (which it sounds like you said you have done:

```
<select name="foo[]" multiple="multiple"> 
    <!-- options go here -->
</select>
```

and then in your php you have access to them as an array like this:

```
<?php
    // This will print out all of the selected values.
    print_r($_GET['foo']);
```

To echo these results in a table:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Option</th></tr>
    <?php foreach ($_GET['foo'] as $option) : ?>
        <tr><td><?php echo htmlspecialchars($option) ?></td></tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: I added your code to the top of my page. The table is empty, but on the top it says "Array ( [0] => HASAN MIZRAK [1] => SERDAR KAPLAN )"

Comment: Yeah so that means that HASAN MIZRAK and SERDAR KAPLAN were the two selected options if you want to echo the results in a table see my updated post.

Comment: Yes, the selected options are listed in table but that's not what I need. I need them to be used in the query and bring the results filtered with these two salesmen.

Answer (score 0):

`name="satici[]" multiple="multiple"` is correct HTML.

What you want to do in php would be:

```
$arr_search = array();
foreach((array)@$_POST['satici'] as $h)
    $arr_search[] = $h; // Escape this value (without "'")

$str_search = implode('|', $arr_search);
```

And inside the query, replace for instance `WHERE satis_satici LIKE %s` with `WHERE satis_satici REGEXP '{$str_search}'`.

Note that `col LIKE 'search'` is often equal to `col REGEXP 'search'` and `col LIKE 'search' OR col LIKE 'search'` is often equal to `col REGEXP 'search|search2'`, which my example provides.

Apart from that, I'd advice you to get the variables, column names and such to english as much as possible. It becomes much easier to maintain, and you only need to translate to the end user.

Comment: Robin, thanks for your fast reply and suggestions. I'll keep that in mind. I tried your code but it gave me that error: "Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp". I put the code just before sql query and changed the query with your code.

Comment: Whats does `print_r($_POST['satici'])` give you?

Comment: Before or after your code? I tried that with chrislondon's solution yesterday. It wasn't the exact thing I need but it was giving me the two names I chose after the query. But now it gives the same error again "Got error 'empty (sub)expression' from regexp".

Comment: I'd recommend you to troubleshoot this. [Google your error](https://www.google.se/search?q=mysql+Got+error+%27empty+%28sub%29expression%27+from+regexp), see what `$str_search` gives and such. It's hard to help with the little details in this case, especially when I find your code difficult to read.

Comment: Robin, though I don't think I can find the solution by googling, 'cause I've been doing that hopelessly for three days. Thank you anyway. At least you tried.

Comment: Reset your current thoughts, be open minded and troubleshoot everything from the sql query by echo'ng the same string, check the values passed and read up more on the `multiple` attribute. Just approach this with a new and fresh mind, and the solution will come to you.